# Объединить функции в javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции, chrome-extension

Здравствуйте ! Я новичок в этой всей теме, так что есть глупый вопрос.

Есть у меня расширение для google chrome.

В нем я обычным колдовством получаю код страницы другого сайта.

```
function AvtoBumpBot2() {

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/", true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) 
        {
            if (xhr.responseText) 
            {
               var data = xhr.responseText;
               var gl= $('.profile_leftcol', data);
               var count = gl.children('.tradeoffer').size();

               if (count > 0) {

                 // Вот здесь и нужно повторить все то же самое, но уже с другим url'ом.

               }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Собственно нужно повторить все то же самое, но уже с другим url'ом в нутри асинхронной ф-и.

Как мне это реализовать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я тебя правильно понял, то примерно так:

```
function AvtoBumpBot2(url) {

    if(!url){var url = "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/"} //если url не задан - url по умолчанию

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);

    [...]//для краткости, не буду повторять весь твой код

    if (count > 0) {
         var url2 = "http://skazochnik.org/";//новый url 
         AvtoBumpBot2(url2);//Вызываем ту же ф-цию, но уже с новым url
         //В принципе, можно было и так AvtoBumpBot2("http://skazochnik.org/");
    }

    [...]

 }
```

Comment: Тут моя ошибка, я немного не дописал вопрос. Например если count = 3, то мне нужно спарсить 3 разных ссылки и запомнить одно значение с каждой в переменную. (a += a например).

Comment: Немного не понял. Приведи пример или опиши подробнее. Сейчас я могу только догадываться, что из себя представляет твое .tradeoffer, которые ты считаешь и зачем ты к а прибовляешь а. Возможно, фрагмент вестки, который ты пытаешься обработать, поможет разрешить задачу

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы спарсить сайт - пройди в два этапа.
1- пособирай ссылки (как ты это делаеш) и запиши их в json или кудато.
2- пройдись по собраным ссылкам из json  и сделай что нужно.